# mongoDB database location in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Where exactly is the database stored when you run the following script in node.js?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

Is there a db file?

Comment: Wherever your mongo server is set up to keep them.

Answer (score 1):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";
//         ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑   ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ ↑↑↑↑↑ ↑↑↑↑
//         └ protocol  |       |     └the database name
//                     |       └port
//                     └your local machine

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

If you want to see the data stored, you can either use the following command from your terminal:

```
mongo
// connects to your local MongoDB server

use mydb 
// switches to that database
db.yourCollectionName.find({}) 
// for example
```

or if you want a gui, download [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB databases are stored in the mongodb server which means before you can be able to access the database , your mongodb server should be running. If you have installed MongoDB Server. Just run this command to show all your databases

```
show dbs
```

Once you do that, you should see all your mongodb databases.

Answer (score 0):

**For Linux:**

The default location of MongoDB server is `/data/db` . You can specify the location while initializing the mongod daemon with `--dbpath` option followed by the required location

---

**For Windows:**

While installing the Mongo server in your system, the installer prompts you to enter the default location for storing the database and the logs.

[image: MongoDB Setup Dialog]

The default location is usually `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\x.x\data\`